# Setting a ListView row height

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I've got a problem in my application.

I use a ListView to show my products.
I can't get the effect, where every item shows all over the screen.
I mean, so that each row inherits height.

Here is my ListView layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4">
    <!-- Main ListView
         Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
    -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:background="@color/pod_logo">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/iVlogo_obiekty"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_akme"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="NAZWA OBIEKTU"
            android:id="@+id/tV_nazwa_obiektu"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:background="@color/niebieski"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Product id (pid) - will be HIDDEN - used to pass to other activity -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <!-- Name Label -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="#123456"

        android:text="TEXT"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I changed the concept and i now want something like this on picture:

[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjuVc.png)

Someone want to help me ? Pls. I dont know what i must change:/

Comment: you mean you want all list items to have the same height?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I wish every line had the same height and inherit from listview.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set the row height programmatically. Note that the code below is untested/from memory, so it may require some tweaks, but essentially it grabs the height of the screen in your Adapter's constructor (or somewhere else) and stores it to `screenHeight`. You can then use it to set the height of each row in `getView()`:

```
private int screenHeight;
//...
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
//...

@Override
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if( convertView == null ){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    }
    LayoutParams params = convertView.getLayoutParams();
    if (params.height != screenHeight) params.height = screenHeight;

    convertView.setLayoutParams(params);

    return convertView;
}
```

**Edit:** Note that the above code assumes you pass a `Context` argument in your Adapter's constructor, or you could just pass the `screenHeight` directly, etc.

Comment: is it possible to do it by other way, maybe in layout xml?

Comment: @kamilos207 I don't think so - not if you are experiencing issues with `match_parent`

Comment: Maybe you have suggestions on how to accomplish this? I have no idea and and this programmaticaly way it is for me not understandable.

Comment: @kamilos207 Ok - what kind of adapter are you using for your `ListView`?